# : Access denied for user 'kalinaresidence_sample'@'localhost in mysql for wrong username

Tags: codeigniter

I created folder inside public_html as sample .I am working on codeigniter project.  I changed in database.php in config folder but i am getting access denied for wrong username Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'kalinaresidence_sample'@'localhost' (using password: YES) .I am stucking in this issue . I attached error screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ47O.png)

I am facing issue in codeignter project.I am working on codeigniter project.

Comment: Please check your Mysql User table, if the said use & host match. Also check the password field for special characters or whitespace
Try to login first via command line mysql -u USER_NAME -P  
For reference please read : https://blog.devart.com/mysql-command-line-client.html